# generate independent arrays of random numbers with cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, curand

I need to generate many random numbers. I have found a lot of documentation on how to generate one array of random numbers. But, I need to generate 4 independent arrays of random numbers. For example, generate independently the components of a 4-vector (x, y, z, t). With the following code I generate one array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

using namespace std;


//Give a randState to each CUDA thread from which it can sample from
__global__ void init_rng(unsigned int seed, curandState* state)
{
    unsigned int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    curand_init(seed, idx, 0, &state[idx]);
}

__global__ void gen_x(curandState *state, float* x)
{
   unsigned int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

      curandState localState = state[idx];
      x[idx] = curand_uniform(&localState);
      state[idx] = localState;
}

int main(void)
{

   long int N = 1E+6;
   int threadsPerBlock = 1024;
   int nBlocks = (N + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;

   float *x;
   //Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
   cudaMallocManaged((void**)&x, N*sizeof(float));

   // Create a device pointer on the host, to hold the random states
   curandState *d_state;
   //Malloc number of states equal to number of threads
   cudaMalloc((void**)&d_state, N*sizeof(curandState));
   // Init the random states
   init_rng<<<nBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(12345, d_state);

   gen_x<<<nBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_state, x);
}
```

How could I also generate other independent random arrays, say "y", "z" and "t" without any correlation between them? Should I create 4 different kernels for each one initiallized to a different seed reusing the curandstate, or is there a way to do it on the same kernel?
Thank you!

Comment: [a good-quality pseudo random number generator aims to produce uncorrelated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), even for non-overlapping subsequences within a single sequence (e.g. a single seed). You should be able to generate `y` and the others the same way you are generating `x`, as a trivial addition to the kernel you already have e.g. `y[idx] = curand_uniform(&localState);` etc. If you feel otherwise you should state why you think so. The only concern for a single sequence is exceeding the period and this is unlikely for typical use of a high quality PRNG

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you so much for the clarifications and your quick reply. I got confused by the example in the cuRAND Library Programming Guide about the device CURAND API to calculate what proportion of quasi-random 3D points fall within a sphere of radius 1, where they use different states for each dimension, which is not needed for the pseudo-random case. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I also generate other independent random arrays, say "y", "z" and "t" without any correlation between them?

It should be sufficient to do something like this:

```
__global__ void gen_xyzt(curandState *state, float* x, float *y, float *z, float *t)
{
   unsigned int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

      curandState localState = state[idx];
      x[idx] = curand_uniform(&localState);
      y[idx] = curand_uniform(&localState);
      z[idx] = curand_uniform(&localState);
      t[idx] = curand_uniform(&localState);
      state[idx] = localState;
}
```

A Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG) of high quality [seeks to emulate a random sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).  Such a sequence has the statistics you are looking for, for this case.

The caveats are that a PRNG usually does not have "perfect" statistics (but using multiple generators may not fix this) and also such sequences have periods.  The period is the sequence length at which the sequence repeats, overlaps another sequence, or has some other undesirable behavior.  Typical CURAND PRNGs have long sequences, such that generating, say 2^64 numbers won't exceed [the period](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#bit-generation-1).